# Eclipse does not show MySQL driver when creating a new database connection

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am attempting to create a Database Connection to MySQL. I right click on connections and select create a new connection. I then select MySQL. There are no drivers displayed in the drop down list and I cannot seem to go on any further. I just reloaded MySQL with Connector/J. No luck.

I am using the Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627 and MySQL mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.17.0

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Willie

Answer (score 0):

When in the new connection window click on the Jar List tab and select the mysql connector jar that you will need to connect to a mysqldb from java. You should then see drivers become available to create a db connection with.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Go to Eclipse Market Place

Step 2. Search key word by "Data Tools"

Step 3. Install "Eclipse DTP"

[image]

Comment: I don't find DTP in marketplace. I'm using latest Spring Tool Suite 4.

Answer (score 0):

seems like, you don't have MySQL driver pre-installed. So download the appropriate jar version of the driver for your project and point that location in the eclipse Preferences configuration.
Follow the steps given in this blog in detail:
https://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/add-mysql-jdbc-driver-to-eclipse.html

Comment: I went to Windows -> Preferences -> Data Management -> Connectivity -> Driver Definitions. I tried to add new driver definition but did not find MySQL in Vendor Filter.